# Casting C++ types with ARC in objective-c

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, casting

Stumbled with the following situation:

I work with a 3-rd party C++ library.

lib's header:

```
#define lib_fname               char 
typedef lib_fname*              lib_l_fname;

Function(lib_l_fname name);
```

my code(I need to call that func):

```
Function ((lib_l_fname)[@"name" UTF8String]);
```

This worked in not-ARC project, but in with ARC i have an error - "Cast of an Objective-C pointer to lib_l_fname (aka char*)  is disallowed with ARC"

I tried

```
  Function ([@"name" UTF8String]);
```

But it didn't work. Is there a solution?

Comment: http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=919981

Comment: didn't find anything helpful,unfortunately

Comment: You need to copy it first (with `strcpy`) because that function returns an internal pointer of the `NSString` object.  I don't know why it would cause this error in particular, but maybe it will go away if you do that (and you need to do it anyway).

Comment: I don't experience such problem. I use LLVM 5.0 compiler. It compiles without errors and warnings. UTF8String method returns pointer to C string, thus copying shouldn't change anything.

Comment: `Function ((lib_l_fname)@"name" )` would cause the above compiler error, but not `Function ((lib_l_fname)[@"name" UTF8String])`.

Comment: answered myself,@borrrden was right

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

Compiling with arc is more strict and it gives errors when trying to cast const char* to char*.

The solution was to create  a second string char* and to strcpy there [@"name" UTF8String]

```
 char str2[1024] = {0};
 strcpy(str2, [@"name" UTF8String]);

 Function ((lib_l_fname)str2);
```

works as expected

Comment: What about `CFStringGetCString(CFSTR("name"),...)`?

Comment: Also, why even bother with the NSString? Can't you use `strcpy( str2, "name")`?

Comment: "name" - was just for explicit. Actually it's a variable like object.filepath of type NSString

Comment: In that case, you might consider `CFStringGetCString((__bridge CFStringRef)theNSString, ...)` or even `CFStringGetCStringPtr((__bridge CFStringRef)theNSString,...)`